# MySQL ranking conditions from two tables

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, ranking

I have two tables: first with users' data (name: users) and second with users' statistics (name: users_stats). Below I put my ranking MySQL query (working with one table: users_stats):

```
SELECT  d.*, c.ranks FROM (
    SELECT sold, @rank:=@rank+1 ranks FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.`sold` FROM users_stats a ORDER BY sold DESC
    ) t, 
    (SELECT @rank:= 0) 
r) c 
INNER JOIN users_stats d ON c.sold = d.sold 
WHERE login = 'XXXXXX'

RESULTS:
LOGIN_1 - 50 SOLD - RANK 1 (ACTIVE) 
LOGIN_2 - 40 SOLD - RANK 2 (ACTIVE) 
LOGIN_3 - 40 SOLD - RANK 2 (ACTIVE)
LOGIN_4 - 30 SOLD - RANK 3 (BLOCKED)
LOGIN_5 - 20 SOLD - RANK 4 (ACTIVE)
```

I want to add to this query account active condition because I do not want to rank were among inactive or blocked persons.

I tried put condition to query:

```
SELECT  d.*, c.ranks FROM (
    SELECT sold, @rank:=@rank+1 ranks FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.`sold` FROM users_stats a ORDER BY sold DESC
    ) t, 
    (SELECT @rank:= 0) 
r) c 
INNER JOIN users_stats d ON c.sold = d.sold 
WHERE login = 'XXXXXX'  
AND `login` IN (SELECT b.`login` FROM `users` b WHERE b.`active` = 'YES')
```

...but I get skipped ranking position, for example:

```
RESULTS: 
LOGIN_1 - 50 SOLD - RANK 1 (ACTIVE) 
LOGIN_2 - 40 SOLD - RANK 2 (ACTIVE) 
LOGIN_3 - 40 SOLD - RANK 2 (ACTIVE) 
LOGIN_4 - 20 SOLD - RANK 4 (ACTIVE)
```

I would be glad for any clue! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is doing too much work, I think.  You don't need to do the `distinct` in a subquery, you can just enumerate the `sold` values directly.  This requires two variables and a bit more logic.

In any case, the answer to your question is to do the `join` when you select the `sold` values.  Here is one method:

```
  SELECT us.*,
         (@rank := if(@s = sold, @rank + 1,
                      if(@s := sold, 1, 1)
                     )
         ) as rank
  FROM users_stats us JOIN
       users u
       ON us.login = u.login CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT @rank:= 0, @s := 0) params
 WHERE u.login = 'XXXXXX'
 ORDER BY sold,  DESC
```

Comment: I get 'Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in..." when I put your query. Can you add condition with user's active?

Comment: @RafałKonarski . . . Subqueries need aliases in MySQL, even for defining constants.

Comment: Opss... I didn't see "params" in query... :) Thanks!